# Cain and Abel in Sefer ha-Ikkarim

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, yosef-albo

[This article](https://www.rabbisacks.org/covenant-conversation/tzav/violence-and-the-sacred/) by Rabbi Sacks z”l states that, according to Sefer ha-Ikkarim, Cain killed Abel as a human sacrifice (believing that that was the best way of paying tribute to Hashem). But the actual wording of Sefer ha-Ikkarim, at 3:15, explicitly says that Cain killed Abel out of wrathful jealousy (נכנסה קנאה בלב קין והרג את הבל). What gives?

Comment: Oh interesting! It never occurred to me to read it that way!

Comment: I don't buy it. "Jealousy entered his heart" sounds a lot more plausible than "zeal entered his heart."

Comment: In Islamic tradition Cain killed Abel because he wanted to marry his twin sister and not Abel's as Adam would have liked, so the offering that each one made was Adam's idea to seek from God an answer to what he intended, God he accepted Abel's offer for him to marry Cain's twin sister, which Cain did not like and out of jealousy he did what he did. It is not a Jewish source but refers to the issue of jealousy proposed by the Sefer in question.

Comment: @Thales The [midrash](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.22.7?lang=bi) says Abel had an extra twin sister and they were arguing over who should marry her.

Comment: @shmosel So on your reading (“jealousy”), which was also my reading to begin with, how does Rabbi Sacks infer human sacrifice?

Comment: I'm not sure. As far as I can tell it's only saying that Cain inferred from G-d's acceptance of Abel's sacrifice that it was permissible to kill any living creature, on which basis he allowed himself to take revenge on Abel.

Comment: @Shmosel But wrathful revenge, and calculated human sacrifice, are totally different things.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.15.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he - for assistance

Comment: @Zarka I'm agreeing with you.

Answer (score 1):

The full quote in the Sefer HaIkkarim is [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaIkkarim%2C_Maamar_3.15.6?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> ובעבור זה נכנסה קנאה בלב קין והרג את הבל, בהיותו נמשך אחר כונתו
> הראשונה שאין לאדם יתרון על הבעלי חיים, ואמר בלבו כי אחר שהשם יתברך שעה
> אל הבל ואל מנחתו, נראה שהוא מותר להרוג את הבעלי חיים וחשב שאין בהריגת
> הבל איסור יותר מבהריגת אחד מבעלי חיים

> And because of this, jealousy entered Cain's heart and he killed Abel, since he was drawn to his first belief that man has no advantage over animals, and he said in his heart that after the Lord blessed Abel and his offering, it seems that he is allowed to kill the animals and thought that killing Abel is no more forbidden than killing one of the animals ...

In a sense, Cain viewed Hevel like any other animal offering. The Sefer HaIkkarim goes on to say that Cain was unaware that the offering of a human was different from the offering of an animal. Cain's "first belief" was that of seeing no advantage of man over animals; so perhaps this is what Rabbi Sacks is referring to i.e., the jealousy is a secondary element.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about killing him as an offering. Just that Cain thought killing humans was as permissible as killing animals.

Comment: Good contribution and seems to imply that Rabbi Sacks, z"l didn't properly understand either the account of Kayin and Hevel,  or what Rabbi Albo was writing in Sefer HaIkkarim. What the midrash Sefer Yashar and also the text from Sefer Yovelim add to the account helps a great deal to understand what Rabbi Albo is actually saying. There is no opinion that Kayin had good intentions in this whole process. That presumption is not in keeping with what the Torah recounts in either the written or oral Torah.